# Unity IoC Explicitly ask container for new instance

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

It appears that Unity IoC defaults to creating a new instance of an object when it resolves a type.  But my question is there someway to be explicit and tell my container that whenever I have it resolve an object type to give me a new instance of said type?

IE i want to be explicit and force the container to make sure theInstance is a new instance each time it resolves type:MyNewObject (or all types for that matter)

```
MyNewObject theInstance = container.Resolve<MyNewObject>();
```

Comment: Im concerned about the objects lifecycle because its an mvc3 app and i want to make sure that each web request instiates a new instance of my controllers.  I think if i register them to the container as oleskii describes I will get a new controller instance per request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is easily configurable by a [TransientLifetimeManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.transientlifetimemanager.aspx)

When you register a class should have something like

```
container.Register<IMyNewObject, MyMewObject>(new TransientLifetimeManager());
//or
container.Register<MyMewObject>(new TransientLifetimeManager())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're applying IoC principles properly, your class declares its dependencies and then **the container handles the lifecycles of them**. For example, you want to grab an HttpRequest object and the container handles providing the current thread-local one, or whatever.

Your code shouldn't really have to care about the life-cycle of its dependencies, as it should never be responsible for clearing up after them or what-have-you (all of that should be encapsulated in the dependency itself, and invoked by the container when it is shut down).

However, if you do need to care in your code about whether you get a singleton instance or a per-injected instance of the same type, I like to be explicit about it by using the type system itself, just as the Guice container for Java does with its [`Provider`](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectingProviders) pattern. I've created a Guice-style `IProvider<T>` interface that I use to do this, and I just wire it up with a simple static factory method for them like so:

```
Provider.Of<Foo>(() => { /* Code to return a Foo goes here */})
```